# yii2 rules not applying to non-db attributes?

Tags: forms, validation, yii2, rules, modelattribute

I would like to upload multiple files at once. I have

a model:

```
class KakiKingModel extends ActiveRecord {

    public $uploadedFiles;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['uploadedFiles'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'txt', 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false, 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'maxFiles' => 2]];
    }
    ...
```

controller:

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
...
public function actionUpload() {
    $model = new KakiKingModel;
    $t = new KakiKingModel;

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'uploadedFiles');

        $t = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($files as $i => $file) {
            $t[$i] = new KakiKingModel;
            $t[$i]->contentUploadedFile = file($file->tempName);
            $t[$i]->assign(); // assign file content to model attributes
            $i++;
        }

        if (Model::validateMultiple($t)) {
            foreach ($t as $item) {
                $item->save(false);
            }
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('upload', [
                        'model' => $model,
                        't' => $t,
            ]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', [
                'model' => $model,
                't' => $t,
    ]);
}
```

view:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    ....
    'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    ...
        <?= $form->field($model, 'uploadedFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true]) ?>
```

and the problem is, it accepts any other type of files also! Why is that? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!
UPDATE: I have changed my content a bit, so that you can better understand why I find it disturbing that it doesn't work. It should work IMHO. Can you please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yii2 validation rules are applied for non-database model attributes too.

I think there are two common reasons for this problem:

**1)** Make sure you add correct `enctype` for sending files to server:

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

...

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
```

**2)** [yii\validators\FileValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html) ([aliased](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html) with `file`) works only with [yii\web\UploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html) class instances (it's abstraction of PHP native superglobal [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array), make sure you assign correct value to attribute before it's validated.

For single file use [\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstance%28%29-detail):

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

...

$this->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'file');
```

For multiple files use [\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile.html#getInstances%28%29-detail):

```
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

...

$this->files = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'files');
```

This can be done right before calling `$model->save()` or `$model->validate()` or inside of `beforeValidate()` event handler:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeValidate()
{
    $this->files = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'files');

    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

Comment: okay, I hope I understand it. So the problem is, that somehow this assignment happens **after** validation by me? But at the moment, this command is tied to a `if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {...` statement. Maybe a lame question, but how do I mix it with this `beforeValidate()` thing then...?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way in your model:

```
    namespace app\models;

    use yii\base\Model;
    use yii\web\UploadedFile;

    /**
    * UploadForm is the model behind the upload form.
    */
    class UploadForm extends Model
    {
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile|Null file attribute
     */
   public $uploadedFiles;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['uploadedFiles'], 'file'],
        ];
    }
    }
    ?>
```

IN view :

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'uploadedFiles')->fileInput() ?>

<button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: I've tried, but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: your are missing something plz check your code once again , and try to dry run.

Comment: what am I missing? I've tried also without `[]`, but no change.